# "Входная строка имела неверный формат." при взаимодействии с SQL Server через Win Forms

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, winforms

Я не могу найти ошибку в запросе, или даже не могу понять в чем может быть ошибка. При нажатии на кнопку данные должны вноситься в указанное поле в БД. Сама ошибка "Входная строка имела неверный формат.". Типы данных сверял, везде указал конвертирование в нужный формат. HELP пожалуйста

```
if (textBox10 != null)
                {
                query1 = $"UPDATE [BooksMain] SET [Цена]={Convert.ToDecimal(textBox10.Text)} WHERE [Код книги]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text)}";
                    command = new SqlCommand(query1, myConnection);
                }
```

весь код блока:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        myConnection.Open();

            string query = $"SELECT [Код книги] FROM [BooksMain] WHERE [Код книги]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text)}";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if ((textBox18 != null) & reader.Read())
            {
                string query1;

                MessageBox.Show("Успешно");

                if (textBox10 != null)
                {
                    query1 = $"UPDATE [BooksMain] SET [Цена]={Convert.ToDecimal(textBox10.Text)} WHERE [Код книги]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text)}";
                    command = new SqlCommand(query1, myConnection);
                }

                if (textBox11 != null)
                {
                    query1 = $"UPDATE [BooksMain] SET [Количество экземпляров]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text)} WHERE [Код книги]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text)}";
                    command = new SqlCommand(query1, myConnection);
                }

                if (textBox12 != null)
                {
                    query1 = $"UPDATE [BooksMain] SET [Издательство]={Convert.ToString(textBox12.Text)} WHERE [Код книги]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text)}";
                    command = new SqlCommand(query1, myConnection);
                }

                if (textBox13 != null)
                {
                    query1 = $"UPDATE [BooksMain] SET [Год издания]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox13.Text)} WHERE [Код книги]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text)}";
                    command = new SqlCommand(query1, myConnection);
                }

                if (textBox14 != null)
                {
                    query1 = $"UPDATE [BooksMain] SET [Автор]={Convert.ToString(textBox14.Text)} WHERE [Код книги]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text)}";
                    command = new SqlCommand(query1, myConnection);
                }

                if (textBox15 != null)
                {
                    query1 = $"UPDATE [BooksMain] SET [Название]={Convert.ToString(textBox15.Text)} WHERE [Код книги]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text)}";
                    command = new SqlCommand(query1, myConnection);
                }

                if (textBox16 != null)
                {
                     query1 = $"UPDATE [BooksMain] SET [Код жанра]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox16.Text)} WHERE [Код книги]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text)}";
                     command = new SqlCommand(query1, myConnection);
                }                                     

                if (textBox17 != null)
                {
                    query1 = $"UPDATE [BooksMain] SET [Код поставки]={Convert.ToString(textBox17.Text)} WHERE [Код книги]={Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text)}";
                    command = new SqlCommand(query1, myConnection);
                }



            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Введите действительный код книги");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строка `textBox18.Text` не может быть конвертирована в целое, или, скорее, строка `textBox10.Text` не может быть конвертирована в `Decimal`. Наиболее вероятно, что дело в десятичном разделителе.

Comment: Попробовал удалить строку (таких условий много для каждого поля). Следующее поле выдает такую же ошибку. В textBox18.Text ввожу целые числа (код товара), не представляю как оно может не конвертироваться в int.

Comment: Добавил к посту весь код блока, может там что то не так. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: "Попробовал удалить строку" - Я не понимаю, что это значит, и не могу догадаться.

Comment: строку кода с условием где  Convert.ToDecimal.

Comment: @Dendislam Вынесите конвертацию в числа из SQL строк

Comment: Попробовал, еще попробовал закомментировать все условия куда я не собираюсь вводить данные. Ошибка пропала, то есть неправильно задано условие if (textBoxXX != null), потому что то что внутри него все равно выполняется. В текстбоксе куда ввожу данные ошибки не вылазят, но данные в бд не заносятся((

Comment: @Dendislam Вы со мной беседуете так, как будто я вижу Ваш код (и мысли).